# Half height of the div show in slodedown effect?

Tags: jquery, animation, slidedown

I have one div with height say 100px and it is hidden in page load. When I click on another link, I want to display half of its height(50px) on sudden by using just show() and rest 50px should display in slide-down effect. How its possible, any help  ?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow like this maybe:

```
$("#linkClick").click(function() {
    $("#yourDiv").css("height", "50px");
    $("#yourDiv").show();
    $("#yourDiv").slideDown();
});
```

Hope it helps.